# Use 3G for internet and WiFi for LAN in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g

I am developing an android app to stream movies from local server on a WiFi. The WiFi does not have internet, it will be used only for accessing the streaming server.

What would make the app kickass is that the app users can continue using internet on their 3G while connected to my WiFi and streaming the movie.

I know for a fact that when android connects to a WIFI, the phone under the hood makes a call to `clients.google.com/generate_204` to check if internet is available on the WIFI. If it receives no response, it continues using 3G along with being connected to the WiFi. However, in this scenario if my app makes a request to say `192.168.24.5` (ip address of my streaming server), it does not use WiFi to reach this ip but hunts for this address on 3G and fails.

What i need to achieve is that when android is connected to both my wifi and 3G, any call to private ip is directed to WiFi whereas any call to internet should use 3G.

Can this be done and how?

Comment: And your Wifi network uses the IP range 192.168.24.x?

Comment: Yeah actually my LAN WiFi range is 192.168.24.x .and my streaming server is connected to WAN port of the router, hosted on ip 192.168.10.2